# how to `echo` 'formatted' man page of some command to text file

Tags: command-line, echo

When I execute

```
echo `man ls` > tem.txt
```

I get unformatted output in the text file, I mean output without any new lines, just continues sentences. How do I get formatted output ?

For example, unformatted output looks like:

```
LS(1) User Commands LS(1) NAME ls - list directory contents SYNOPSIS ls
[OPTION]... [FILE]... DESCRIPTION List information about the FILEs (the
current directory by default). Sort entries alphabetically if none of -
cftuvSUX nor --sort is speci‐ fied. Mandatory arguments to long options are
mandatory for short options too. -a.................
```

Comment: Why not do redirect man's output directly? Also, even if you use echo, why haven't you quoted it?

Comment: how do you redirect directly ?

Comment: `man ls > tem.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to force `man`'s output via process substitution. Redirection works fine for it:

```
man ls > tem.txt
```

Even if you so use process substitution, remember to use quotes, otherwise the output will undergo splitting + globbing from the shell:

```
echo "$(man ls)" > tem.txt
```

Comment: how does double quotes help ?

Comment: globbing is performed on wildcards and commands right ? how on output ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds A command line is processed in several stages. Command substitution takes place before the globbing stage. So if the command's output contains wildcards, it will be expanded. Quoting works normally: prevents the shell from expanding wildcards and compressing and replacing all whitespace with spaces.